# Find word in string by index

Tags: c#

i am trying to get a word in a string by a specified index, a word may only consist of letters and digits.

i have tried the specified code but unfortunately it generates the following exception: "Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length". which i guess happens on line 18. please help.

the goal of the code is to get a word by a specified index.

```
private string WordByIndex(string text, int index)
{
  try
  {
    int start = index;
    int end = index;

    while (char.IsLetterOrDigit(text[start]))
    {
      start--;
    }
    start++;

    while (char.IsLetterOrDigit(text[end]))
    {
      end++;
    }

    return text.Substring(start, end - start);
  }
  catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
}
```

Comment: You don't consider `start < 0` or `end >= text.Length`. You then increment `start` if it does ever exit the loop, and if it's a single letter word like `a`, means that `start > end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to keep start and end inside the bounds of your string:

```
private string WordByIndex(string text, int index)
{
    int start = index;
    int end = index;

    while (start >= 1 && char.IsLetterOrDigit(text[start - 1]))
    {
        start--;
    }

    while (end < text.Length && char.IsLetterOrDigit(text[end]))
    {
        end++;
    }

    return text.Substring(start, end - start);
}
```

(I removed your try-catch-block as it does nothing atm)

Your approach has the benefit of not creating superflous string copies or using a regex

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/vFacCN

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
private  string WordByIndex(string text, int index)
{
    try
    {
        int start = index;

        while (char.IsLetterOrDigit(text[start]))
        {
            start--;
        }
        start++;

        text= text.Substring(start); 

        var result=Regex.Match(text,@"[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}");

        return result.Value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
    }
```

See the working example on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r3h7jI)

Hope it helps